# Is it possible to do port forwarding by nginx when the port is not open?

Tags: hadoop, nginx, centos

building hadoop with hortonworks ambari. total 7 nodes. 
Only 80 and 8080 port are allowed to use. 
It needs to be shown some web UI such as Nifi..

Is it possible to open Nifi web ui thorough nginx?

ambari admin page address is node1:8080 and nginx address node2:80.

I set nginx.conf as below...

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost;

    location / {
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   html;
    }

    # for nifi
    location = /nifi {
        proxy_pass http://0.0.0.0:9090/nifi;

    }
```

But nifi show me error log like below..
2019/03/27 17:39:15 [error] 14804#0: *122 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: xxx.xxx.xx.xx, server: localhost, request: "GET /nifi HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://0.0.0.0:9090/nifi", host: "xxx.xxx.xx.xx"

It seems to needs another port 9088 as nifi protocol...
I don't think it can be resolved with nginx... 
Do I need to request to use those port available?
Please give me your advice....

Comment: Are you really using 0.0.0.0 as the upstream IP? That works as a bind address (bind to all IPv4 interfaces), but you can't connect to it.

Comment: I tried 127.0.0.1 and localhost. It seems to send me same response...

Comment: Connection refused in the error log means the service you're trying to connect to via proxy_pass isn't listening on the provided URI. If you're using containers, that could be a reason. Without more information it's only possible to speculate.